# Folder and file operations

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB but I need to achieve these in my project using VB.

I have a file `target.file` at local. There is a `target` folder on network server. There are several hundred folders under `target`. There are `backup` folders under some of those folders.

I need to copy `target.file` to those folders under the `target` folder, but only copy/replace if there is already a `target.file` existing. If the `target.file` exists, copy and replace the file to the backup folder if the backup folder exists. If not, create the backup folder first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I perform this file/ folder distribution task; SSIS or command script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961064/how-should-i-perform-this-file-folder-distribution-task-ssis-or-command-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the methods in `System.IO` namespace. Take a look at the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), there is a lot of interesting and useful classes, specially [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This are the methods that looks like you will need:

- [**File.Exists()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): Checks if a file exists on the path given.
- [**File.Copy()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): Copies the file on the path given.
- [**Directory.Exists()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): Checks if a directory exists on the path given.
- [**Directory.CreateDirectory()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): Creates all the directories that doesnt exists on the path given.

However, you didn't need to check if the file exists because you can copy directly with the overwrite option enabled:

```
File.Copy(sourceFile, destPathFile, True) 'True for overwrite
```