# Trying to create a program that would allow user to copy files from a certain directory to another. replacing similar file on it's destination

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim d As String
    d = "K:\example\" & SaveComboBox1.Text & "\" & SaveComboBox2.Text & "\" & "ward.txt"

    If objFSO.fileexists(d) Then
        objFile = objFSO.GetFile(d)
        objFile.delete(True)
        objFSO.CopyFile(d, "K:\example\ward.txt")
    End If
    objFSO.CopyFile(d, "K:\example\ward.txt")
```

.inputs would come from 2 combobox selections..It asks to make sure that the file existed, but the file really do exist

Comment: Did you check the filename by debugging for any invalid characters?

Comment: If you're using VB.NET then use VB.NET.  `Path.Combine`, `File.Exists`, `File.Copy`.  The `File.Copy` method lets you overwrite an existing file, so no need to even look.

Comment: Yes I did and it would state Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0035 (CTL_E_FILENOTFOUND)

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978894/how-to-copy-replace-a-file-into-a-folder-in-vb-net

Comment: First off, I don't really see the question here. What is the problem that you are having? Does the above throw an error? If so, what error and where?

Comment: Second, I notice that you have `objFSO.CopyFile(d, "K:\example\ward.txt")` in there twice: once inside the `If` and again after it. In a situation where the file does already exist, the new file will be copied twice, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Third, I do agree with @jmcilhinney that you should be using the methods they suggested to handle the files, but I feel I should point out that per the [msdn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method)  `CopyFile` will override any existing file by default, so there is no reason you should have to check if it exists and delete it.